# Matching, filtering and grouping in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list-comprehension

I have a folder containing some images of the format:

```
wheel_0.jpg, tyre_2.jpg
```

but also some other formats:

```
bar_0.heic
```

and files like that (that I don't want to match):

```
hello.jpg
```

I want to create a list of image names that are jpeg format, do not finish by _0 and add them without their extension.
I already made this piece of code that works fine:

```
images = os.listdir("images")
images_to_search = []
for image in images:
    re_obj = re.search("(.+)(_\d+)(\..+)", image)
    if re_obj:
        if re_obj.group(3) == ".jpg" and re_obj.group(2) != "_0":
            images_to_search.append(re.sub("\.jpg", '', image))
```

Is there any way to make this for loo into a list comprehension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re

images = os.listdir("images")
rx = re.compile(r'.+_(?!0\.)\d+\.jpg$')
images_to_search = [x.rsplit('.')[0] for x in filter(rx.match, images)]
# => ['tyre_2']
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VysXJ4/2). The regex matches

- `.+` - any one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `_(?!0\.)\d+` - `_` not followed with `0.` and then one or more digits
- `\.jpg` - `.jpg` text.

The `re.match` requires a match to occur only at the string start, no need prepending the pattern with `^`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6rTXdG):

```py
images = ['tyre_2.jpg', 'bar_0.heic', 'hello.jpg', 'wheel_0.jpg']
import re
rx = re.compile(r'.+_(?!0\.)\d+\.jpg$')
print([x.rsplit('.')[0] for x in filter(rx.match, images)])
# => ['tyre_2']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this without using `re`, like so

```
>>> [f.replace(".jpg","") for f in images if "_" in f and f.endswith(".jpg") and not f.endswith("_0.jpg")]
```

Comment: @CômeSchaeffer - Edited :)

Answer (score 0):

```
images = os.listdir('images')
images_to_search = [image for image in images if re.search("(.+)(_\d+)(\..+)", image).group(3) == '.jpg' and re.search("(.+)(_\d+)(\..+)", image).group(2) != '_0')
```

Comment: I already tried this one but it doesn't work when the image name doesn't match the 3 groups

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
images = [x[:-4] for x in images if (x[-4:]==".jpg")&(x[-4:]!="_0.jpg")]
```

Comment: Should be `x[-5:]!="_0.jpg"`. Also `images` is the list of file names and the name of your new list, which could be a little confusing.

Comment: I think it should be more `[x[:-4] for x in images if (x[-4:]==".jpg")&(x[-6:]!="_0.jpg")]` but it matches hello.jpg that I don't want